# map concern hash keys with the table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a concern in model

```
module Employee
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def job
      job_hash = {
        '0': 'A',
        '1': 'B',
        '2': 'C'
       }.freeze
       job_hash[:"#{@job}"]
  end
end
```

I have model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'Jobs'
  include Employee
end
```

Jobs table has column type that has values 0, 1, 2 
How can i map the values from hash (0,1,2) in concern with column type and return the string value associated with it? so if the user type is 1 then return B

Thanks

Comment: This question makes no sense at all - what are you trying to acheive and more importantly why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just decouple the `#job` method and use it like this (if I'm understanding you correctly):

```
module Employee
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def job
      job_mapping[:"#{@job}"]
    end

    def job_mapping
      {
        '0' => 'A',
        '1' => 'B',
        '2' =>  'C'
      }
    end

    def job_name
      job_mapping[type.to_s]
    end
  end
end


company = Company.find(some_id)
job_name = company.job_name
```

On an unrelated note, `freeze`ing something that is in an instance method is a code smell, you probably want to promote that to a constant if possible.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony. If i want to create a method to get job_name how could i do that in model or can i directly do that in controller then save result to instance variable and call in JSON?

Comment: You could do it in the concern or the model, see the new edit.

Comment: I created the method but keep getting job_name null

Comment: is `type` a string in the database or an int?

Comment: then in the `job_name` method, do `job_mapping[type.to_s]`

Comment: still getting null. When I put byebug in method. i am getting column value but when i look for job_mapping[type.to_s] i get null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136367/discussion-between-anthony-and-user4432432432).